# Is Nokia Lumia 930 getting Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-930

I've been reading that some models have already got this update and was wondering if 930 is ever going to get it.

I have my 930 for a day now with Preview for Developers installed but I haven't got that update.

Have anyone got it without doing any tricks??

Is it planned for this phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Denim is currently the latest update available to Lumia phones](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/) which is 8.1 Update 1.

Preview for developers was replaced by the Insider Preview programme, which some people have been able to get 8.1 Update 2, as an interim update prior to going to 10.

It has been reported that 8.1 update 2 will not be made widely available to all phones, and most will jump straight to 10.